# Downloaded Riverview twice; savegame kind of broken

Tags: the-sims-3

When I downloaded Riverview to my installation of The Sims 3, the installation seemed to stall, so I aborted it. The second time I tried, it installed fine.

I started a game in Riverview noting that it was listed twice, played for a bit, saved and quit.

Later I had a look at the `InstalledWorlds` folder. It contained:

`Riverview.world` and
`Riverview(1).world`

After deleting `Riverview(1).world` only one Riverview is listed, but my savegame won't load anymore.
One way to fix this would be to simply rename `Riverview.world` to `Riverview(1).world`, but I'd really prefer to get my savegame to use the regular file name. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I stopped playing the neighborhood in question and simply kept only `Riverview.sims3` around.

Answer (score -1):

To solve the issue, copy the meta data file into both the numbered folders, deleted the regular `Riverview.sims3` folder, and renamed the folders to their original names.

So probably if it's not loading maybe you should have transferred the meta data file from `Riverview(1).sims3` to `Riverview.sims` before deleting it.

Since the meta data file is gone from your successful installment, I think you have no choice but to play with the new files.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. `Riverview.sims3` is a file, not a folder, and `Riverview(1).sims3` is perfectly identical to it. How would I go about "transferring metadata" between them?